# What is the best thing to do if the agreed salary set by you and team leader is not the same on the new contract?

Tags: software-industry, raise, salaried-pay

I talked with my team leader and asked for a salary raise. 
We agreed on the amount of X Euros.
When the new contract came the salary on the paper was X-25 Euros.

I know that 25 Euros is not that much, but what is the best thing to do in this situation?

Comment: Possibly a rounding error related to converting between different pay periods?  I.e. an annual salary of €90,000  is a weekly salary of €1730.76923.  If this were entered as a €1730 weekly salary, your total for the year would be €89,960.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ask why they did that.

Usually there is some annoying (pseudo)legal reason for these things. Something incredibly stupid and petty.

Maybe they just forgot.

Either way they you'll have to accept the lower salary or they will go "oops, sorry, here is the extra 25€"

CC the team lead too, if he is a good team lead he'll be annoyed that HR broke his promise to you.

If neither of these people care, run for the hills. Companies willing to scam you the petty things will be willing to scam you on the big ones.

Comment: Totally agree specially with the last sentence. If they play games with you for just 25 euro, they'll probably stab you in the back for something more important.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph.